# Turtle will not draw in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I am having an issue with turtle not drawing images when executing in pycharm.

The window comes up and stays open, but the cursor just sits there.  It is not executing the instructions to draw the image as needed.  This is in 2 separate files, main.py and turtle.cfg file.

main.py has this code in it

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.width(2)
t.pencolor("red")


def square(t, length):
    for count in range(4):
        t.forward(length)
        t.left(90)



square()
turtle.done()
```

and turtle.cfg has this in it

```
width = 300
height = 200
using_IDLE = True
colormode = 255
```

That's it.  It should be super simple, and yet for some reason when I open it, the cursor just sits in the center of the screen and goes nowhere.  For transparency, this is copied directly from my text book as a learning example, so I would think that it *should* work.

Comment: Defining a function is pointless if you do not actually call it...

Comment: For future readers, the author edited and added the `square()` call after receiving an answer. The code in the question will run as intended. Flagging to close as caused by typo.

Comment: Lol good looking out blackbrandt.

Answer (score 2):

the function `square` was never called, so it never runs, you can try placing `square(t, 40)` (or another number) right before `turtle.done()` like so:

```py
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.width(2)
t.pencolor("red")


def square(t, length):
    for count in range(4):
        t.forward(length)
        t.left(90)

square(t, 40)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Yeah I don't know why I didn't think of that ahead of time.  I was just using the code straight from the book, thinking it would auto-execute.  I think the books example was meant to be put in IDLE.  Well that was a fun embarrassment lol.

Comment: Probably a mistake on their side then, even on the IDLE the function wouldn't run as you define it. It's fine anyway, these kinds of stuff happen all the time lol

Comment: Yeah it turns out it's the assignment that has the error.  The entire section of the chapter has me making a total of 5 fuctions, 3 shapes and 2 radials using those shapes.  Nothing gets a call until the very end, but they wanted us to run each step and screenshot it.